# Spring integration TCP, force reconnect

Tags: spring, tcp, spring-integration, reconnect

I have the following spring integration TCP connection:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client" type="client" host="..." port="..." single-use="true" so-timeout="10000"/>
```

I wish to be able to force a reconnect when a protocol-level problem occurs. Can that be done? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have `single-use` set to `true`, a socket is only used once per request so "reconnecting on a failure" makes no sense because a new connection will be established for each request anyway.

With `single-use="false"` (shared connection), if you are using the factory with an `<int-ip:output-channel-adapter/>` you can set `client-mode` to true; this will automatically reconnect after a timeout (and you can explicitly re-establish the shared connection by invoking `retryConnection()` on the adapter. `client-mode` is not currently supported on the outbound gateway, however. See [TCP Adapters](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-adapters) and use your browser to find 'client-mode' for more information.

That said, with `single-use="false"`, you can simply call `getConnection()` on the client factory and it will re-establish the shared connection (but you must not do anything with the connection). Also, don't do this with `single-use="true"` however, because it will cause a memory leak (unless you `close()` the connection - which would make no sense - getting a connection just to close it).